# Is it still appropriate to use Bower to install Bootstrap instead of via NPM or NuGet?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, asp.net-core, bower

I'm checking out tons of blogs like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bootstrap) where it's explicitly stated that Bower is the preferred and recommended way install Bootstrap to my Core web app.

> The recommended way to install client-side dependencies like Bootstrap in ASP.NET Core is via Bower (using bower.json, as shown above). The use of npm/NuGet are shown to demonstrate how easily Bootstrap can be added to other kinds of web applications, including earlier versions of ASP.NET.

Checking the date of the post seems to be settling as it's only a few weeks old but when I check e.g. the icon for dependencies and some other things, I'm getting the impression that the content might be actually a bit more aged than so.

I've been googlearching lately and I learned that there's a shift towards fewer-simpler-smaller approach. Especially I've discovered that NPM is often recommended for managing all the packages, including Bootstrap. (Now, just because someone says so, it doesn't automatically makes it true - we need to ask **why** would the one or the other approach be more advantageous.)

Question - what's the downside of using Bower to manage Bootstrap instead of installing it with NPM and omitting Bower all together?

Comment: Subjective question, subjective comment :P There is no real downside, other than that you have to manage two files in case you need npm too.Bowers first intention is to provide client libraries (which run in browser) where npm provices nodejs packages which can also run on server side. npm has a few more packages, especially when it comes to creating bundles or running gulp or grunt tasks.So if you need both, you have to manage two files with bower were you only need one for npm.On other side, bower restores its packages in wwwroot/lib folder, npm doesn't so it needs to be copied over via task

Comment: I think the short answer is it doesn't really matter, ie - as far as your project goes you should have more important decisions to think about.  Twitter supports install from either of these methods and in the grand scheme of things the differences are minimal.  For example, if you're already using npm as the core of your build process, then its nice to keep it simple and not introduce something new, like bower.  Luckily, you have the flexibility to choose.

Comment: @Tseng That's a great answer. Post it so I can give you some rep.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that since bootstrap is a strictly front-end framework, the recommendation was to install it via bower. If you envision having server-side javascript in your project as well, then npm would be the recommended way to go now :)